# I am stuck at this step C(AB+A'B')(simplify using boolean laws)

Tags: logic-gates, boolean-algebra

[image]
I cant figure out is AB+A'B' =1 or another answer

Comment: By the way, ABC+A'B'C+AB = AB(C+1)+A'B'C=AB+A'B'C. Still this cant be simplified more.

Comment: Thank you sir ......

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you are really asking.

\$AB+\overline{A}\text{ }\overline{B}\$ is not equal to 1 or 0. It is exactly what it is. You could find equivalent expressions but you can't really simplify this as long as you restrict yourself to AND, OR and NOT operators.

Comment: No  dear. I want to know AB+A'B' = 0 (Because A+A'=0 )

Comment: @Tharindi A + A' = 1, not 0. Instead, (A A') = 0.

Comment: AB+A'B' is not equal to 0 and it is not equal to 1. I don't know how to be more clear about this.